# Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql:// on aws EC2 instance

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-mvc, amazon-ec2

I have a war file deployed on tomcat server running on aws ec2 instance. Whenever I tried to restart my tomcat I got these exception

```
Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://xyz.com:5432/db
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
```

Earlier I thought it may be happening because of the wrong url, but I executed the application locally with the same `application.properties` file and it worked. I was able to connect to the db server which is again running on another instance of aws ec2. So I don't think it's happening because of wrong url.

Is it because of one of my aws ec2 instance is not being able to connect to the db server instance ? How can I resolve this ?

**EDIT :**  I have tried adding inbound rules for both the aws ec2 instances, still same issue.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, I should have known this. The issue here is that postgresql jdbc driver was missing. And that's what the error keep saying.

I just added the postgresql driver jar file in PATH_TO_TOMCAT_DIR/lib, and it worked.

Anyway posting this so that in future it might help others.